# How to make SMS and mobile calls?

Tags: software-recommendation, network-manager, modem

Will there be a way to send sms and make calls using mobile broadbands in 12.04?

(If there is a 3rd party app rather than Wammu-Gammu, please mention)

Comment: That depends on your GSM provider i think , there might be API suitable , but I'm not sure

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution by myself!!
[Betavine Connection Manager](https://forge.betavine.net/frs/?group_id=76) can manage messages! That's it.
Also try, KMobileTools, Vodafone Connection Manager!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use modem manager gui from ubuntu reposatory. for new ubuntu 14.04 it is so advanced can send sms and run USSD codes also.